# The PHP code has no errors executing , Insert operation successful , but data not present in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, insert

The PHP Code Below is to insert the form details into my MySQL database,
but dont know where the problem is.
No Error are Displayed and a message displays "Insert Operation Successful"

The PHP Code Below is to insert the form details into my MySQL database,
but dont know where the problem is.
No Error are Displayed and a message displays "Insert Operation Successful"

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Nihanth-HomePage</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
#body{
    background-image:url(images/diamond.jpg);
}
#navbar{
    margin-bottom:0px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
#aaa{
    background:#FFFFFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="body">
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Nihanth</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="myprojects.php">My Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid" id="aaa">
<?php
$server_host="localhost";
$server_user="*******";
$db_name="********";
$server_pass="******";
$table="Medha_2k16";
$con = mysqli_connect($server_host, $server_user, $server_pass, $db_name) or die("Server Connection Failed");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
<?php
$sname=$_POST['sname'];
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$branch=$_POST['branch'];
$college=$_POST['college'];
$quiz=$_POST['quiz'];
$cd=$_POST['cd'];
$md=$_POST['md'];
$iwd=$_POST['iwd'];
$elocution=$_POST['elocution'];
$rp=$_POST['rp'];
$ep=$_POST['ep'];
$sp=$_POST['sp'];
$pp=$_POST['pp'];
$ppt=$_POST['ppt'];
echo $sname;echo "<br><br>";
echo $pin;echo "<br><br>";
echo $phone;echo "<br><br>";
echo $email;echo "<br><br>";
echo $branch;echo "<br><br>";
echo $college;echo "<br><br>";
echo $quiz;echo "<br><br>";
echo $cd;echo "<br><br>";
echo $iwd;echo "<br><br>";
echo $elocution;echo "<br><br>";
echo $rp;echo "<br><br>";
echo $ep;echo "<br><br>";
echo $sp;echo "<br><br>";
echo $pp;echo "<br><br>";
echo $ppt;echo "<br><br>";

mysqli_query($con , "INSERT INTO Medha_2k16 (sname, pin, email, phone, branch, college, quiz, cd, iwd, elocution, sp, md, rp, ep, ppt, pp) VALUES ($sname,$pin,$email,$phone,$branch,$college,$quiz,$cd,$iwd,$elocution,$sp,$md,$rp,$ep,$ppt,$pp)");

if((mysqli_query)==true)
{
  printf("Insert Operation Successful");    
}
else
{
    printf(" Unable to INSERT\n %d ",mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_error($con);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pls check up the question there is no form element at all in the code that you have posted. Post the form along with this page by editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used the `php variables` inside the query string, so it is taken as a `string`, not `variable`. their values could not be used. Instead you need to separate it from the query string so that it can be processed.

**Replace:**

```
mysqli_query($con , "INSERT INTO Medha_2k16 (sname, pin, email, phone, branch, college, quiz, cd, iwd, elocution, sp, md, rp, ep, ppt, pp) VALUES ($sname,$pin,$email,$phone,$branch,$college,$quiz,$cd,$iwd,$elocution,$sp,$md,$rp,$ep,$ppt,$pp)");
```

**with:**

```
mysqli_query($con , "INSERT INTO Medha_2k16 (sname, pin, email, phone, branch, college, quiz, cd, iwd, elocution, sp, md, rp, ep, ppt, pp) VALUES (" '.$sname.'"," '.$pin.'"," '.$email.'"," '.$phone.'"," '.$branch.'"," '.$college.'"," '.$quiz.'"," '.$cd.'"," '.$iwd.'"," '.$elocution.'"," '.$sp.'"," '.$md.'"," '.$rp.'"," '.$ep.'"," '.$ppt.'"," '.$pp.'")");
```

This should work for you.